# Powershell - How to split a string based on characters?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of pdf filenames that need to be parsed and ultimately sent to a sql table, with the parse out pieces each in their own column.  How would I split based on a dash '-' and ultimately get it into a table.

What cmdlets would you start with to split on a character?  I need to split based on the dash '-'.

Thanks for the help.

**Example File Names:**

- tester-2458-full_contact_snapshot-20200115_1188.pdf
- tester-2458-limited_contact_snapshot-20200119_9330.pdf

**Desired Results:**

[image]

Comment: `-split`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a `-split` operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split

basic example:

if you have file names in `$FilePaths` array.

```
foreach($filepath in $FilePaths)
{
  $parts = $filepath -split '-'; 
  [pscustomobject]@{"User" = $parts[0]; "AppID" = $parts[1]; "FileType" = $parts[2]; "FilePath"=$filepath }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nasir, this is helpful and does split it as desired.  How would I get the -split results into a column format.  I piped it to format-table, but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: A basic version: 
`$parts = $filepath -split '-';`
`[pscustomobject]@{"User" = $parts[0]; "AppID" = $parts[1]; "FileType" = $parts[2]; "FilePath"=$filepath}`

Answer (score 1):

Use $variable.split('-') which will return a string array with a length equal to however many elements are produced by the split operation.

Comment: Nasir and LordPupazz answers successfully split the filename

Answer (score 1):

yet another way is to use regex & named capture groups. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a set of file name strings to work with
  when ready to use real data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use either `(Get-ChildItem).Name` or another method that gives you plain strings.
- iterates thru the collection of file name strings
- uses `$Null =` to suppress the `False/True` output of the `-match` call
- does a regex match with named capture groups
- uses the `$Match` automatic variable to plug the captured values into the desired properties of a `[PSCustomObject]`
- sends that PSCO out to the `$Results` collection
- displays that on screen
- sends it to a CSV for later use

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a list of file names
#    in real life, use (Get-ChildItem).Name
$InStuff = @'
tester-2458-full_contact_snapshot-20200115_1188.pdf
tester-2458-limited_contact_snapshot-20200119_9330.pdf
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a list of file names

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '^(?<User>.+)-(?<AppId>.+)-(?<FileType>.+)-(?<Date>.+)\.pdf$'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        User = $Matches.User
        AppId = $Matches.AppId
        FileType = $Matches.FileType
        Date = $Matches.Date
        FileName = $IS_Item
        }
    }

# display on screen    
$Results

# send to CSV file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\JM1_-_FileReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

output to screen ...

```
User     : tester
AppId    : 2458
FileType : full_contact_snapshot
Date     : 20200115_1188
FileName : tester-2458-full_contact_snapshot-20200115_1188.pdf

User     : tester
AppId    : 2458
FileType : limited_contact_snapshot
Date     : 20200119_9330
FileName : tester-2458-limited_contact_snapshot-20200119_9330.pdf
```

content of the `C:\Temp\JM1_-_FileReport.csv` file ...

```
"User","AppId","FileType","Date","FileName"
"tester","2458","full_contact_snapshot","20200115_1188","tester-2458-full_contact_snapshot-20200115_1188.pdf"
"tester","2458","limited_contact_snapshot","20200119_9330","tester-2458-limited_contact_snapshot-20200119_9330.pdf"
```

Comment: For anyone trying to understand regex, there are some helpful tools I learned about from this article:  https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/ in the section 'Regex Resources'.  The one that's helped me the most so far is https://regex101.com/.

Comment: @JM1 - i use `regex101.com` rather often ... it is a truly lovely resource! [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey for your response.  I'm trying to understand it before I ask you anything further.  I'm still not getting what the question mark and <User> are doing in this bit:  (?<User>.+) .

Comment: When adding the real code, I added a Format-Table to the results to ultimately get to my goal.  The other answers did split the path, but this most fully answered the need to ultimately put the results into a table in the overall request.  Thanks @Lee_Dailey and all who responded.

Comment: @JM1 - the `(?<NameOfThing>.=)` is how you do a named capture group. the `?<>` part is specially for that purpose. ///// please be VERY careful of the `Format-*` cmdlets. they _destroy_ your objects, wrap the butchered bits in formatting code, and then send that out. they are for FINAL output to screen or a plain text file. if you need to use the data later, then stick with `Select-Object.///// you are very welcome! i'm glad to have helped a bit! [*grin*]

Comment: For anyone else looking into Regex, another tool I found to be the most helpful so far, is rubular.com.  It enables you to put a sample test string and write your regex against it to see if it works.